# JavaScript Nesting For Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code where I fail to understand some parts:

```
var arr = [
[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
  console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

What does arr[i] mean? I have been told that arr[i] itself is an array. How is that? And What is happening in the arr[i][j] part?

Comment: `arr[i]` - Get element at `i`th index from `arr`. `arr[i][j]` get item at `j`th index from `arr[i]` array.

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger, examining variables at each point, such as `arr[i]` and `arr[i][j]`. The meaning of `arr[i]` will be described in any basic tutorial on JS in the part where it discusses arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`i` variable iterates over the arrays (*nested arrays*) inside the `arr` variable, so if it looks like e.g. `arr[2]`, it returns the third array inside the `arr` (because the index starts with 0), which is - `[5,6]`.

`j` stands for iterating over elements inside the nested arrays, so if it is like `arr[2][1]` - it returns `6`, because `6` is the element inside the `arr[2]` array with `1` index.

Comment: Does this answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
//position   0       1       2
```

//array[i]

`array[0]`-> return an array of [1,2]

//array[i][j]

`array[0][0]` ->return value of the first array in the first position -> 1

in your case you iterate for the length of the array, inside it you iterate for the length of the array[i], so in your console you must have the value from 1 to 6

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add comments and rewrite to explain what's happening a little better. Play with the code until you understand what's happening!

```js
// A 2-dimension array (or "array of arrays").
// You can think of this as a matrix by row and column.
var arr = [
//      col 0    col 1 
       [    1,       2], // row 0 
       [    3,       4], // row 1 
       [    5,       6], // row 2
];

// Loop over rows.
for (var r = 0; r < arr.length; r++) {
 // The "row" is the array at index r.
 var row = arr[r];
 // Loop over columns.
 for (var c = 0; c < row.length; c++) {
  // Print the value at row "r" and column "c".
  console.log(`row ${r}, column ${c} = ${row[c]}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
```

What you have is a multidimensional array.  This means that it is an array with arrays inside of it.

```
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

This means that while `i` is less than the length of `arr` (in this example 3, since the items inside of it are [1,2], [3,4], and [5,6] which adds up to a total of 3 items) do what ever is in the `for` statement and once you finish add 1 to `i`.

```
for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
```

Same as above but when we are getting the length `arr[i]`.  This means that whatever `i` is, look at the item in `arr` that is at that position.  So when `i = 0`, `arr[i] = [1,2]`.  when `i = 1`, `arr[i] = [3,4]`.

```
console.log(arr[i][j]);
```

Write to the console the item found at position `j` from the array at position `i` in `arr`.  So, if `i = 0` and `j = 0`, the console would read `1`.  This is because `arr` at 0 is [1, 2] and the item at the 0 position in that array is 1.  if `i = 0` and `j = 1` it would print `2`.  If `i = 1` and `j = 0` the console will read `3`.

Hope this explain everything to you clearly.